# How to change UILabel frame on the basis of its child frame in Auto Layout environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout, addsubview

I am customizing `UILabel`. All I want to do is set a custom view inside `UILabel`. I added the label's width and height constraint to greater than 100. Now when I add sub view to label, I want to update the label's frame according to its child's frame. How can I achieve this?

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the label's size to always be greater than or equal to its subview's size?

Comment: @Austin Yes. this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First, lower the priority of the width and height constraint to 800 or so. Then, add constraints so that the label is always at least as tall and wide as its subview:

```
[self.label addSubview:otherView];
[self.label addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[otherView]->=0-|"
  options:0
  metrics:nil
  views:@{@"otherView" : otherView}]];
[self.label addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[otherView]->=0-|"
  options:0
  metrics:nil
  views:@{@"otherView" : otherView}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the other way. As I am looking for a way in which I do not need to deal with constraints and It will behave as it was configured. For that I have Derived UILabel and created a Custom Label. Then I implemented `addSubView` and `intrinsicSize` methods as below:

```
@implement MxCustomLabel

@synthesize dummyView;

- (void) addSubView:(UIView*)view
{
    self.dummyView = view;

    [self invalidateIntrinsicSize];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [super addSubView:view];

        });

}

-(CGSize) intrinsicSize
{
   return CGSizeMake(self.dummyView.frame.size.width, self.dummyView.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

Only thing to take care is to set Label's `width` and `height` constraints to `greater than or equal` in interface builder. If it is set to `equals` then this implement will respect constraint and will not enlarge. However, if you set either height OR width to `greater than or equal` then this implement will expand the size for corresponding constrain.

In this similar manner we can design custom component from all basic components which are derived from `UIView`.

Although, it has limitation that, it will `grow` parent UIView from `center`. we can not control the growing direction. If this also can be achieved then it will be awesome.